# Redmine receiving emails from imap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap, redmine

I have installed Redmine 2.6.1-stable, it works using apache2 and passenger.
I'm trying to receive emails using imap with this two rakes:

this one:

```
rake -f /opt/redmine-2.6.1/Rakefile --silent redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=smtp.yandex.ru port=465 username=mail@yandex.ru password=pwd ssl=true project=desk folder=INBOX move_on_success=processed move_on_failure=failed no_permission_check=1 unknown_user=accept
```

And this one:

```
bundle exec rake redmine:email:receive_imap host='smtp.yandex.ru' username='mail@yandex.ru' password='pwd' port=465 ssl=true starttls=true allow_override=type,project project=desk
```

And this is log:

```
** Invoke redmine:email:receive_imap (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_imap
rake aborted!
EOFError: end of file reached
/home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/imap.rb:1150:in `get_tagged_response'
/home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/imap.rb:1210:in `block in send_command'
/home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/imap.rb:1192:in `send_command'
/home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/imap.rb:435:in `login'
/opt/redmine-2.6.1/lib/redmine/imap.rb:30:in `check'
/opt/redmine-2.6.1/lib/tasks/email.rake:128:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-2.6.1/app/models/mailer.rb:367:in `with_synched_deliveries'
/opt/redmine-2.6.1/lib/tasks/email.rake:127:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:email:receive_imap
```

I can't understand what's going on.. Why it does not work properly?

Log `/opt/redmine-2.6.1/logs/production.log` is empty about this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to receive IMAP email from an SMTP server.  These are completely different protocols.

Likely you want server imap.yandex.ru, Port 993, with SSL (not starttls).

Settings for IMAP appear to be available at https://yandex.com/support/mail/mail-clients.xml

Answer (score 2):

I recently solved my similar problem with enabling debug on IMAP, so I could see what's happened. To do that;

`vim /var/www/redmine/lib/redmine/imap.rb`

and after require 'net/imap' add this line:

`Net::IMAP.debug = true`

It usually relates to the login credentials/method.